# Unable to Load Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to load a bootstrap modal but it is not working in my website.
When i tried to see on console i got following errors.

In Firefox:

```
TypeError: e.modal(...).one is not a function   bootstrap.js:6
```

In Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.js:6
```

My Code :

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#myModal10" role="button" data-toggle="modal">More Info</a>
<div id="myModal10" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Contributors</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>This is a Contributors Membership. You will have a 365 day Membership where your organization can post listings the whole year with coupon membership is free. (Please Contact for Code if you haven't already received it)</p>          
          </div>

        </div>
        </div></div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: works fine on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f5vGL/ , make sure call  bootstrap js is true

Comment: Thanks. I think there is jquery conflict problem. please check it live site : http://www.helpinghawaiinei.org/wp-login.php?action=register

Comment: Check your js references order. I think this is because of conflict in js files.

Comment: Yes. may be js conflict. I tried to use jquery noConflict. But unable to solve the problem. My live site is http://www.helpinghawaiinei.org/wp-login.php?action=register Can you please tell me how exactly can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think js conflict with `jquery.simplemodal.1.4.3.min.js` include with `jquery-migrate.min.js` but not sure ..

Try with add bootstrap.js after call `jquery-migrate.min.js` and `jquery.simplemodal.1.4.3.min.js`

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpinghawaiinei.org/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpinghawaiinei.org/wp-content/plugins/ajax-event-calendar/js/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.3.min.js?ver=1.4.3'></script>
<script src="http://www.helpinghawaiinei.org/wp-content/themes/AT/framework/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g9r8r/